# Ignore tee in linux script

Tags: linux, unix, command, tee

I have a .sh script on a red hat machine:

```
{
statement 1
statement 2
statement 3
etc....
} 2>&1 | tee "logdir/logfile.log"
```

which logs both to the console and into logfile logfile.com. However, statement 2 is giving a lot of output and I wish to exclude that from the logfile, while still showing output in the console.

Is there a way to exclude a specific statement from the tee to the logfile?

**EDIT**:
A bit of clarification on the statements:

```
{
echo some information on the environment
echo some checks

rsync  -rtpgov /some/folder/ some/other/folder

tar -xf some/other/tar/file.tar  -C some/other/folder2
tar -xf some/other/tar/file.tar  -C some/other/folder3
tar -xf some/other/tar/file.tar  -C some/other/folder4
etc...

echo  some finishing checks
} 2>&1 | tee "logdir/logfile.log"
```

I wish to exclude the rsync from writing to the logfile.log while still seeing the output in the console.

Comment: Could you show a bit more of your code before the statement? Could you put a condition, if (statement 2) before or are the statements only existing inside your function ?

Answer (score 0):

Once `tee` is processing, can you see what lines should be excluded?

When you only know this when you are processing statement 2, it looks like you need to change each statement.

```
rm "logdir/logfile.log"
{
   echo 1 2>&1 | tee "logdir/logfile.log"
   echo 2 2>&1
   echo 3 2>&1 | tee -a "logdir/logfile.log"
} 2>&1
echo ===
echo "Contents File "logdir/logfile.log"
cat "logdir/logfile.log"
```

When statement 2 shows different kind of output, you can focus on that

```
rm "logdir/logfile.log"
{
   echo 1 useful
   echo 2 debug
   echo 3 this I want
} 2>&1 | tee >(grep -Ev "debug|trace|other garbage" > "logdir/logfile.log")
echo ===
echo "File "logdir/logfile.log":"
cat "logdir/logfile.log"
```

When you do not know what statement 2 will say, but want to filter this one without changing the other lines, you can make a workaround:

```
rm "logdir/logfile.log"
{
   echo 1 useful
   echo 2 debug | sed 's/^/FREEZE/'
   echo 3 this I want
} 2>&1 | tee >(grep "^FREEZE" > "logdir/logfile.log") | sed 's/^FREEZE//'
echo ===
echo "File "logdir/logfile.log":"
cat "logdir/logfile.log"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a simple workable solution myself:

```
{
echo some information on the environment
echo some checks
# etc....
} 2>&1 | tee "logdir/logfile.log"    

{
rsync  -rtpgov /some/folder/ some/other/folder
} 2>&1 | tee "logdir/rsync.log"

{
tar -xf some/other/tar/file.tar  -C some/other/folder2
tar -xf some/other/tar/file.tar  -C some/other/folder3
tar -xf some/other/tar/file.tar  -C some/other/folder4
# etc...

echo  some finishing checks
} 2>&1 | tee -a "logdir/logfile.log"
```

Since the number of statements to log is relatively large and the input into the logfiles varies a lot it seems more convenient to split the logflie into 2. 
Using the -a option the loglines will be appended to the logfile